# React Table v6 expanded subrows after page change

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v6

I am able to show all the subrows on my table using the `defaultExpanded` property like this -

```
const defaultExpandedRows = data.map((element, index) => {
  return { index: true };
});

...

<ReactTable
  ...
  defaultExpanded={defaultExpandedRows}
  ...
/>
```

My problem is that this only works on the initial page load, and when I click on the next page, none of the subrows are expanded.

Page 1, initial load:
[image]

Page 2:
[image]

Is there a way to keep all the subrows open, even after the re-renders from page change?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, just needed to add an `expanded={defaultExpandedRows}`